# How to model the imbalance to predict in different timeframes?

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure, market-making, limit-order-book

As widely shown in this forum and in the literature, the order book imbalance is empirically a good predictor of the market move.

However, even though the calculation of the imbalance is very straight forward, I'd like to ask: how does one model the order book imbalance to try to guess the time (in seconds) at which the future price will likely be impacted by the current imbalance metric?

Let's say that one has a good model that uses the imbalances of the past minute to predict the price 5 seconds ahead o now (could be another timeframe). What's the thought process of creating and validating such model and refining for different assets, so that it can be as precise as possible?

Intuitively for me, the model should be adjusted so that the precision of the model's price prediction based on the imbalance matches the market makers' dt (refresh interval), no?

Comment: The effect of the imbalance is always very short term. I am not sure it makes sense to look at "different time frames". It simply affects the next trade.

Comment: I was looking for a dynamic way to more or less reproduce this, but for a another timeframe https://github.com/grayvalley/microprice-calibration?tab=readme-ov-file